# Evento del google Form de dispara 1, 2 o mas veces

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Con Google Apps script creé una función para crear una nueva hoja de calculo y llenarlo con los datos del Google form y enviarlo por correo con  el evento del form. El trigger esta configurado tal cual para que se ejecute la función al enviar el form.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
}
```

Lleva mas de un año funcionando correctamente pero a partir de la semana pasada al enviar el form se crean 1, 2 o mas documentos e igual numero de envios por correo.

Alguien podría ayudarme con mi problema.

Comment: ¿Has visto mi respuesta? ¿Te ha servido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un problema similar reportado en febrero 2019 en el "issue tracker" [Form submit triggers sporadically fired multiple times with empty events](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124283798) (Activadores al enviar formulario esporáticamente se disparan en múltiples ocasiones con eventos vacíos) el cual sigue abierto.

Cabe aclarar que por eventos vacíos se refieren a que propiedades correspondientes a la respuestas están vacías. Si fuera el mismo caso, uno de los eventos cuenta con datos de respuestas y el resto no, la solución provisional es agregar una condición al inicio de tu función para interrumpir su ejecución.

En el comentario #19 al issue citado  para el caso de evento de formulario en un script vinculado a una hoja de cálculo sugieren lo siguiente:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == e.range.columnEnd) return;

  // El resto de tu código
  // ...
}
```

La condición es que si el rango de la respuestas tiene sólo una columna terminar inmediatamente.

Comment: El problema era por el mismo caso, al agregarle la condición funciona de manera correcta.

Comment: @RicardoSS Gracias por confirmarlo.